# Forcing graphic, table, plot .. out of page boundary

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment

I am very new to latex, so this question might be very basic. However, I have been searching the whole evening, so either I don't know how to google this effectively, or what I am trying to do is not a good practice.

My problem looks the following way:[image]

As can be seen, the plot is too big for the page. In this specific case, I could force it to appear under the first one (I don't know why latex doesn't do this automatically), but later, I have plots which are on their own too big for a page. But as there is a lot of unused space to the left, I would like to use it, and force the plot to appear further to the left. But I could not find out how.

I realize that it is not good to stick to one specific box per page where everything is located and then breach it, and if people agree that one absolutely shouldn't do it, I will have to find another solution.

Thanks for any help.

edit: MWE

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
title=$2\times2$,
bar width=.2cm,
enlargelimits=0.20,
xlabel=Relative share in \%,
ylabel=Dodgson scores,
ytick = data,
xtick = data,
height = 10cm,
width = 2.3cm
]
\addplot+[red!60!white] table[x index=0, y index=1, forget plot] {data/curve_2a.dat};
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=1, fill=red] {data/curve_2b.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
title=$3\times3$,
bar width=.2cm,
enlargelimits=0.15,
xlabel=Relative share in \%,
ylabel=Dodgson scores,
ytick = data,
height = 10cm,
width = 3cm
]
\addplot+[red!60!white] table[x index=0, y index=1, forget plot] {data/curve_3a.dat};
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=1, fill=red] {data/curve_3b.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... and so forth. A total of 12 which get bigger with the amount of data they represent.

edit2: Since I am already asking a question and am showing my plots, is there an easy way to change one of the plots to red, but keeping it in the style of the basic blue one? Most importantly, just adding +[red!30!white] removed the nice boundaries around the bar. But I think because I used "forget plot", it won't cycle automatically through its presets.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: You can use `\newgeometry` from the `geometry` package to change the page margins etc. temporarily, and then restore the normal values.

Comment: @cfr for a big part, it seems to do exactly what I need. So, working through the next manual it is. Thank you!

Comment: @arecknag if this is solved, please write up a self-answer to take this question off the unanswered list and provide value to future visitors of the site.